# How to check whether a GitHub repository uses Continuous Integration, and which CI platform (e.g. Jenkins, Travis CI)?

Tags: opencv, continuous-integration, github-actions

Is there a simple way to check whether a repository uses continuous integration, and which CI platform (e.g. Jenkins, Travis CI)?

Example: OpenCV. See https://github.com/opencv/opencv. By skimming through the repo, I have no idea whether CI is used (although I supposed so), and what kind of CI it uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most CI platforms use a configuration file or directory placed at the root of the repository. It probably the quickest way to identify the tool used by each repo. Here are a few examples:

- `.travis.yml` for Travis
- `.gitlab-ci.yml` for Gitlab
- `.drone.yml` for Drone CI
- `.circleci/` for CircleCI
- `.github/workflows` for Github

Jenkins situation is slightly more complex since users can have a `Jenkinsfile` directly in there repository or not.